# I have two View.OnTouchListeners, but only one works

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have two OnTouchListeners in my code and every time I run it - even if I change the name of the listener - it does not work.

```
//here is one
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

    // this is for being able to move a spawned image with no id and id not on the activity till created
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (no == 1) ;
                //do nothing
            else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
            }
            _root.invalidate();
            return true;

    }
    return true;

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("             exit")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?." +
                    "your progress will not be saved")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), level.class));

                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}

Button left, right;
ImageView i1, pic2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1_game);

    _root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
    addnumbers = new TextView(this);
    addnumbers.setText(Integer.toString(number));
    _root.addView(addnumbers);

    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    left.setOnTouchListener(this);
    right.setOnTouchListener(this);

    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}
```

Here is the second which is to move a character around the screen

```
public boolean onTouch1(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    i1.getLayoutParams();
            findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.realguy1));
            mParams.leftMargin -= 20;
                i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                break;
            }
        }
```

As I run this code, the one with the OnTouch listener works, but the other does not.

I have done a lot of research, and everything I have tried simply does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two View.OnTouchListeners

Actually, there's only one, and here's why...

`onTouch1` means nothing to the SDK. All you did was define a method. Your compiler might even be telling you that the method is unused.

Both these are going to `onTouch` because that's how `this` here is implied.

```
left.setOnTouchListener(this);
right.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Therefore, **`this`** is the only `View.OnTouchListener` and it's only method is **`onTouch`**.

If you annotated your methods correctly you'd see that. For example,

```
@Override // This is okay
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){ 

}

@Override // Not okay, nothing to override
public boolean onTouch1(View view, MotionEvent event){ 

}
```

---

Now, you could do something like this instead...

Use the one and only `onTouch` method and add a `switch (view.getId())` with a `case` on each button.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){ 
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // left
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // ...
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.button2:
            // right
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // ...
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, it is your decision to refactor that into many separate methods as you see fit.

For example, if you want to keep `onTouch1`, you can delegate `onTouch` to it directly.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){ 
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // left
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // ...
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.button2:
            // right
            return onTouch1(view, event); // delegate to other method
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Also, `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` should never be triggered on a switch using the View ID, so you should remove it

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // Shouldn't work
```

Comment: So sorry i gave you some confusion but i did not understand alot of what you wrote even with the research i did to see if i could understand it

Comment: In your code, you have `switch (v.getId()) { case R.id.button1:`... So do I ;) Now, I only added another case statement for another button ID. That's it!